# How to Get value from textview Results to Alertdialog

Tags: java, android, textview, android-alertdialog

i want when i click the button "mButtonadd" that show an alertdialog and on the alertdialog i want to get the value of "mTextViewResult" ( this is an simple multiplication )

```
private EditText mEditText1;
private TextView mTextViewResult;
private Button mButtonAdd;
int a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_builderdaily);



    mEditText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    a = 15;
    mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mButtonAdd = findViewById(R.id.button);

    mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mEditText1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                mEditText1.setText("0");
            }

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(mEditText1.getText().toString());
            final int sum = num1 * a;
            mTextViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        }

    });

    mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BCdaily.this).create(); //Read Update
            alertDialog.setTitle("hi");

            alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!
        }


    });

}
```

}

i tried to make this code (                 alertDialog.setMessage(mTextViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
 ) but didn't work.

Comment: to get the value, try `mTextViewResult.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your actual problem then Just add one click listener like this :

```
  mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mEditText1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                mEditText1.setText("0");
            }

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(mEditText1.getText().toString());
            final int sum = num1 * a;
            String sumValue = String.valueOf(sum);
            mTextViewResult.setText(sumValue);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BCdaily.this).create(); //Read Update
            alertDialog.setTitle("hi");
            alertDialog.setMessage(sumValue);

            alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `alertDialog.setMessage(mTextViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(sum));`

to

```
mTextViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(sum);
alertDialog.setMessage.setText(mTextViewResult.getText().toString());
```

And another things is that you are using two listener of same `Button`. Do it in same method.
You are using in first `onClick()` to set text in `TextView` and second `onCLick()` showing alertDialog. But You have to use both things in one `Onclick` method not two. Because your have one `button`